# Spring Swagger: Swagger not recognizing controller when passed entity in @RequestBody in POST Method

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, swagger, springfox

I am using swagger2 and following are dependency i have added in pom.xml.

Java Version 1.8

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

My Application Code is: ( I have tried)

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider")
@EnableScheduling
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableSwagger2
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    private static Class<MyApplication> applicationClass = MyApplication.class;

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)
    {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    @Bean
    AuditorAware<Long> auditorProvider()
    {
        return new AuditorAwareImpl();
    }
    
    @Bean
      public Docket productApi() {
        System.out.println("api conf:::");

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
        //    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.package.controller.*"))
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(Api.class))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
      }
    }
```

When adding controller Test1.java,Swagger UI works well

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


import io.swagger.annotations.Api;

@RestController
@Api
public class Test1 {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/checkdomain", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> checkUniqueItemNumber(@RequestHeader(value = "Origin") String origin) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(origin, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Output:[swagger_ui output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PHqJ.png)

When I add in controller i,e test2.java having Request Body of entity (TestEntity.java),application fails

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


import io.swagger.annotations.Api;

@RestController
@Api
public class Test2 {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/check", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> checkUniqueItemNumber2(@RequestBody TestEntity origin) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(origin, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

**TestEntity.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;

@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "TestEntity")
public class TestEntity implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "RecordID")
    private Integer recordID;

    @Column(name="Url")
    private String url;

// generate getter and setter
    
    
}
```

I get the following output,application run fails

[image: Applcation fails Image]

I think it doesn't start tomcat or doesn't it give any log in console.

Thank You, Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

After researching I have found that, application fails when entity contains any manytoone or one to one relationship.